# Android App that redirects to a website URL that does not stay open in the background

Tags: android

So I want the app to act like a shortcut to a website URL.

But what I have now is an app that DOES act like a shortcut to a URL but an empty base "empty activity" opens and stays opened in the background. So when I press back, the default internet browser closes and then the user sees a big white background with my app name on top.

I'm not sure which file to change and how to change it so I can achieve the result I want.

Comment: Why you want an entire app instead of https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen

Comment: just call finish() after you lauch the URL so that it can't come back to your app.